# go to anchor after submitting a ajax form asp.net mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, anchor

I have a search function which uses a mvc 3 ajax form. everything works greate. However becuase the form contains several textboxes and options to choose and because it is an ajax form the user does not notice that the results and he must scroll down to see results. How do I can add an anchor to a ajax form and the user will be redircted (scrolled down) to the anchor, automatically after clicking on the search button? thanks

Answer (score 1):

First you need add callback on successful post request of ajax form:

```
Ajax.BeginForm("Search", new AjaxOptions {OnSuccess = "navigateToSearchResult"})
```

where navigateToSearchResult is javascript function.
 In this function you can specify anchor on the current page:

```
function navigateToSearchResult(result) {
    var elementId = getResultElementIdFromResult(result);
    //set hash to empty because browser doesn't scroll to element
    // if new and current hash are the same 
    window.location.hash = "";
    window.location.hash = "#" + elementId;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will test it and be back to mark your answer as answer